# Twitter data - Finding the most mentioned user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, twitter

Lets say I have stream data from the Twitter API, and I have the data stored as documents in the MongoDB. What I'm trying to find is the count of `screen_name` under `entities.user_mentions`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50657d5844956d06fb5b36c7"),
    "contributors" : null,
    "text" : "",
    "entities" : {
        "urls" : [ ],
        "hashtags" : [
            {
                "text" : "",
                "indices" : [
                    26,
                    30
                ]
            },
            {
                "text" : "",
                "indices" : []
            }
        ],
        "user_mentions" : [ 
                {
                    "name":"Twitter API", 
                    "indices":[4,15], 
                    "screen_name":"twitterapi", 
                    "id":6253282, "id_str":"6253282"
                }]
    },
    ...
```

I have attempted to use map reduce:

```
map = function() {
    if (!this.entities.user_mentions.screen_name) {
        return;
    }

    for (index in this.entities.user_mentions.screen_name) {
        emit(this.entities.user_mentions.screen_name[index], 1);
    }
}

reduce = function(previous, current) {
    var count = 0;

    for (index in current) {
        count += current[index];
    }

    return count;
}

result = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "twitter_sample",
    "map" : map,
    "reduce" : reduce,
    "out" : "user_mentions"
});
```

But its not quite working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `entities.user_mentions` is an array, you want to emit a value for each screen_name in the `map()`:

```
var map = function() {
    this.entities.user_mentions.forEach(function(mention) {
        emit(mention.screen_name, { count: 1 });
    })
};
```

Then count the values by unique screen_name in the `reduce()`:

```
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    // NB: reduce() uses same format as results emitted by map()
    var result = { count: 0 };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
    });

    return result;
};
```

Note: to debug your map/reduce JavaScript functions, you can use `print()` and `printjson()` commands.  The output will appear in your `mongod` log.

EDIT: For comparison, here is an example using the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2:

```
db.twitter_sample.aggregate(
    // Project to limit the document fields included
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "entities.user_mentions" : 1
    }},

    // Split user_mentions array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: "$entities.user_mentions" },

    // Group and count the unique mentions by screen_name
    { $group : {
        _id: "$entities.user_mentions.screen_name",
        count: { $sum : 1 }
    }},

    // Optional: sort by count, descending
    { $sort : {
        "count" : -1
    }}
)
```

The original Map/Reduce approach is best suited for a large data set, as is implied with Twitter data.  For a comparison of Map/Reduce vs Aggregation Framework limitations see the related discussion on the StackOverflow question [MongoDB group(), $group and MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337319/mongodb-group-group-and-mapreduce/12340283#12340283).

Comment: Hats off to you sir. I was wondering can I do the same using the Aggregate Framework? `group()` function?

Comment: @chutsu: You can do the same with the Aggregation Framework, but there are a few caveats such as the results being limited to inline at the moment, and to the maximum document size of 16Mb.  It may also be possible to use the `group()` command, but this also has some limitations.  For a comparison of the approaches and limitations see: [MongoDB group(), $group and MapReduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337319/mongodb-group-group-and-mapreduce/12340283#12340283).

Comment: @chutsu: Added an example with the Aggregation Framework for you ;-)

Comment: hmmm the aggregate version doesn't seem to return the same values as the map reduce version

Comment: @chutsu: How so?  I get the same values for my test, but the data structure is slightly different (`aggregate()` uses `result` instead of `results`, and the `count` is at the the top level rather than nested under `value`).

Comment: Could it be the 16MB limit with the $group operation? Because I read in "MongoDB in Action By Kyle Banker, p96", group() won’t process more than 10,000 unique keys, which might be the case in my test. But I suppose `group() != $group`...

Comment: OMG... @Stennie so sorry, please ignore me I'm an idiot, I was quering the wrong collection...