# Get key, value aggregation of values within an array using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB schema for blog posts that looks like:

```
{
  title: String,
  date: Date,
  description: String,
  tags: [String]
}
```

So, for example, a given blog post might have a document that looks like:

```
{
  title: 'My blog post about MongoDB',
  date: '2020-07-06T07:00:00.000+00:00',
  description: 'A blog about Mongo',
  tags: ['MongoDB', 'Javascript']
}
```

I'm trying to implement a query across my db that returns a **mapping of each tag and a count of how many times that tag appears in the collection**. So, for example if my collection has three posts (A, B, and C), where:

- `A.tags = ['MongoDB', 'Random']`
- `B.tags = ['MongoDB', 'React']`
- `C.tags = ['Nature', 'Random']`

The query would return:

```
[
   { 'MongoDB', 2 },
   { 'Random', 2 },
   { 'React', 1 },
   { 'Nature', 1 },
   { 'Coding', 1 },
]
```

Is there a way to do so using some sort of aggregation pipeline or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB group by array inner-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509045/mongodb-group-by-array-inner-elements)

Comment: @whoami this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible

```
db.collection('blog').aggregate([
     {
      $unwind:{
       path:'$tags' 
       }
     },
     {
      $group:{
        "_id":"$tags",
        "count":{$sum:1}
       }
      }
   }])
```

PS: result format will be different but it will give the correct result you wanted

Comment: that's exactly the same what's given in link above, Please do not add answers for duplicate questions unless OP gets back asking for more help ! It just make redundant questions, try to mark questions as duplicates..

Comment: @whoami i somehow missed your comment! otherwise i would have done the same!