# Querying mongodb for dups but allow certain duplicates based on timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a set of data that have timestamps associated with it. I want mongo to aggregate the ones that have duplicates within a 3 min timestamp. I'll show you an example of what I mean:

Original Data:

```
[{"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:45:18Z"},
 {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:47:18Z"},
 {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:55:18Z"}]
```

After querying, it would be:

```
[{"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:45:18Z"},
 {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:55:18Z"}]
```

Because the second entry was within the 3 min bubble created by the first entry. I've gotten the code so that it aggregates and removed dupes that have the same fruit but now I only want to combine the ones that are within the timestamp bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to do this! First lets split up an hour in 3 minute 'bubbles':

`[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57]`

Now to group these documents we need to modify the timestamp a little. As far I as know this isn't currently possible with the aggregation framework so instead I will use the [`group()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) method.

In order to group fruits within the same time period we need to set the timestamp to the nearest minute 'bubble'. We can do this with `timestamp.minutes -= (timestamp.minutes % 3)`.

Here is the resulting query:

```
db.collection.group({
    keyf: function (doc) {
        var timestamp = new ISODate(doc.timestamp);

        // seconds must be equal across a 'bubble'
        timestamp.setUTCSeconds(0);

        // round down to the nearest 3 minute 'bubble'
        var remainder = timestamp.getUTCMinutes() % 3;
        var bubbleMinute = timestamp.getUTCMinutes() - remainder;
        timestamp.setUTCMinutes(bubbleMinute);

        return { fruit: doc.fruit, 'timestamp': timestamp };
    },
    reduce: function (curr, result) {
        result.sum += 1;
    },
    initial: {
        sum : 0
    }
});
```

Example results:

```
[
    {
        "fruit" : "apple",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-07-17T06:45:00Z"),
        "sum" : 2
    },
    {
        "fruit" : "apple",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-07-17T06:54:00Z"),
        "sum" : 1
    },
    {
        "fruit" : "banana",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-07-17T09:03:00Z"),
        "sum" : 1
    },
    {
        "fruit" : "orange",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-07-17T14:24:00Z"),
        "sum" : 2
    }
]
```

To make this easier you could precompute the 'bubble' timestamp and insert it into the document as a separate field. The documents you create would look something like this:

```
[
    {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:45:18Z", "bubble": "2014-07-17T06:45:00Z"},
    {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:47:18Z", "bubble": "2014-07-17T06:45:00Z"},
    {"fruit" : "apple", "timestamp": "2014-07-17T06:55:18Z", "bubble": "2014-07-17T06:54:00Z"}
]
```

Of course this takes up more storage. However, with this document structure you can use the aggregate function[0].

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    { $group: { _id: { fruit: "$fruit", bubble: "$bubble"} , sum: { $sum: 1 } } },
  ]
)
```

Hope that helps!

[0] [MongoDB aggregation comparison: group(), $group and MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340283/964023)